# How to calculate mean for union of two sets?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, mean, weights

I have a turnover, lets say €10,000 and a number of clients, say 40. So my turnover by client is :

$$ \text{turnover} / \text{number of clients} = 10 000 / 40 = 250$$

However, in fact, I have 2 types of bills. Some clients have only 1 type of bill and others have both. Lets say $x_1$ is client with only type 1 bill, $x_2$ is clients with only type 2 bill and $x_1 \cup x_2$ is client with both types.

I would like to calculate the turnover by client, so i thought about weighted mean. But usually, the denominator is sum of the weight. Here, weights are $x_1$ and $x_2$ but the sum is too high $x1 + x2 >>> c$, some are count both, $x_1 + x_2 \neq c$

**Question**: is it possible to do

$$\frac{(\text{turnover of type 1 bill} \times \text{# of type 1 bill}) + (\text{turnover of type 2 bill} \times \text{# of type 2 bill})}{\text{number of clients}}$$

Comment: You can do whatever you want. Whether it makes sense or not depends on your domain. I'm not sure what a "turnover" is. A weighted mean is correct as long as the weights are non negative. That's the only constraint.